# How to get notified in gdb when memory is freed?

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gdb

I'm debugging a memory issue in C. The piece of memory I'm accessing has been accidentally `free()`:d by somebody else's module. Is there a way in `gdb` to get notified when a piece of memory is `free()`:d?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose your libc's `free`'s argument is called `mem`.

Then, you can print out everything that is freed:

```
(gdb) break __GI___libc_free # this is what my libc's free is actually called
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7af38e0: file malloc.c, line 3698.
(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for when breakpoint 2 is hit, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>print mem
>c
>end
```

Now, every time *anyone* frees anything, you will get a little printout (you can omit `c` if you want it to stop every time `free` occurs):

```
Breakpoint 2, *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x601010) at malloc.c:3698
3698    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
$1 = (void *) 0x601010
```

Or, if you already know what memory address you are interested in, use `cond` to break when someone tries to `free` that address:

```
(gdb) cond 2 (mem==0x601010)
(gdb) c
Breakpoint 3, *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x601010) at malloc.c:3698
3698    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get info about memory leaks the following tools will be really helpful.

1. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)
2. [Google Perf Tools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/wiki/GooglePerformanceTools)

And it doesn't take very long to get used to working with these - definitely worth giving a try.

Or using a hardware watch point to keep track of certain addresses might help - the debugger gets control whenever a read or write happens to the addresses you are watching - but I'm not sure if this offers the exact solution to your problem.

Comment: agree with Raj that this looks like a job for valgrind.